# Recursive removal of trailing whitespace in directory

Tags: bash, ls

Structure

```
/some/dir/a b c d /somedir2/somedir4
/some/dir/abcderf/somedir123/somedir22
```

Problem
Need to recursively remove the trailing whitespace in directories, in the example "`a b c d`" has a whitespace at the end, and "`somedir22`" could have a whitespace on its end which needs removal.

There's hundreds of directories and would like to recursively iterate each directory to check if the directory has a trailing whitespace, and if it does, to rename the directory without the whitespace. Bash is my only option at the moment as this is running on a Western Digital NAS.

Comment: Can you post expected output for the input you provided?

Comment: Sure, I'm hoping to make the directories then from the example like this:
"/some/dir/a b c d/somedir2/somedir4"
"/some/dir/abcderf/somedir123/somedir22"

So that no matter where the directory is located in the path, the individual directories in the path never have a trailing whitespace.

Comment: So like if it finds a directory that has a space at the end of it's name, prompt to rename the directory without the trailing whitespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the worst part is, that each time you `mv` a directory, the directories within that directory change the path.

So we need to make `find` process each subdirectory before the directory itself. Thank you @thatotherguy for the `-depth` option which needs to be passed to `find`. With some fancy `-exec` sh script, we can just `find` all directories that end with trailing space and process each directory's conetnt before the directory itself. For each directory, run a shell script, which removes trailing spaces and `mv`s the directory:

```
find . -type d -regex '.* ' -depth \
    -exec sh -c 'mv -v "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed "s/ *$//")"' -- {} \;
```

@edit I leave my previous answers as a reference:

```
find . -type d -regex '.* ' -printf '%d\t%p\n' |
sort -r -n -k1 | cut -f2- |
xargs -d '\n' -n1 sh -c 'mv -v "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed "s/ *$//")"' --
```

The first two lines get the paths sorted in reverse order according to the depth of the path. So that `"./a /b "` is renamed to `"./a /b "` before `"./a "` get's renamed to `"./a"`. The last command removes the trailing spaces from the path using `sed` and then calls `mv`. Tested it on [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/RiyvBm).

I think we can make the `xargs` line simpler by using perl's rename utility (but it has to be perls, not the one from util-linux):

```
.... |
xargs -d '\n' rename 's/ *$//'
```

Well we could `rename ' ' ''` with util-linux rename, but that would remove all the spaces, we want trailing ones only.

Comment: You can just use `find -depth`

Comment: @thatotherguy Och, there it is, I didn't know about that one. Thank you.